# How to run a C compiled using python

Tags: python, tkinter

Below is code for tkinter to create a button. How can I run a code `./executable` by clicking on this button in Linux

```
import tkinter

master=tkinter.Tk()

master.geometry("100x100")

button1=tkinter.Button(master, text="EXECUTE")
button1.grid(row=1,column=1)    

master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use subprocess to execute a Linux script:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

cmd = 'ls /etc/fstab /etc/non-existent-file'
p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)
output = p.stdout.read()
print (output)
```

I just gave you an example of how to print the output, you can change the cmd variable with the command you want to run.

In order to connect this to tkinter use something similar:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

def execute_script(cmd):
    p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)
    return p.stdout.read()

tkWindow = Tk()

button = Button(tkWindow, command=execute_script('ls'))
```

Comment: `command=execute_script('ls')` should be `command=lambda: execute_script('ls')`.